# How to pipe to a variable with ssh?

Tags: bash

Would it be possible in bash to create a variable and use this variable in the pipe?

So something like this:

```
MYCOMMAND="ssh user@host 'tee -a Log/my.log'"
echo "Hello" | $MYCOMMAND
```

Doing it like the example above gives `tee -a Log/my.log: No such file or directory`
How to do this?

Comment: I suggest to use an array and no variable for this.

Comment: Also see [BashFAQ/050 (I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you try to execute the file `'tee -a Log/my.log'`. You're not executing `tee` with `-a` and `Log/my.log`, but the whole thing as one command. And that command does not exist, hence the `No such file or directory` with the entire filename before it.

`MYCOMMAND="ssh user@host tee -a Log/my.log"` should give better results.

Answer (score 1):

Executing commands within commands, and as part of a downstream pipe, is doable with a bit of escaping.

One easier (?) approach would be the encapsulation of the `ssh/tee` in an array, eg:

```
$ MYCOMMAND=( ssh user@host 'tee -a Log/my.log' )
$ typeset -p MYCOMMAND
declare -a MYCOMMAND=([0]="ssh" [1]="suser@host" [2]="tee -a Log/my.log")

$ echo "Hello" | "${MYCOMMAND[@]}"
Hello

$ ssh user@host 'cat Log/my.log'
Hello
```